# scheme - convert a string to a list without #\ characters and with spaces

Tags: string, split, scheme

If I have a following string after performing some operations - `"this is a string"`
I am trying to convert back to the list - `(this is a string)`
Using the built-in methong `string->list` I get `(#\t #\h #\i #\s #\space #\i #\s #\space #\a #\space #\s #\t #\r #\i #\n #\g #\?)`.
How can I convert it to a list without all the `#\` symbols as well as not having a space be replaced with `#\space`?

Comment: It’s hard to know what you’re asking. The list `(this is a string)` is a list of four symbols, equivalent to `(list 'this 'is 'a 'string)`. Spaces “disappear” because that’s how symbols work. Now, if you truly want a list of characters, `#\x` is really just Scheme’s way of printing the character datatype, so that’s what you’re getting back. If you want a string, surrounded in parentheses, you just need `(string-append "(" str ")")`. It isn’t clear to me from your question why `string->list` isn’t sufficient and what you want the actual output to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have `string-split`, you can still implement it with basic Scheme features.

```
(define (tokenize l)
  (let loop ((t '())
             (l l))
    (if (pair? l)
        (let ((c (car l)))
          (if (char=? c #\space)
              (cons (reverse t) (loop '() (cdr l)))
              (loop (cons (car l) t) (cdr l))))
        (if (null? t)
            '()
            (list (reverse t))))))

(define (string-split s)
  (map list->string (tokenize (string->list s))))

;; (string-split "this is a string") => ("this" "is" "a" "string")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing strings with symbols. To split a string by spaces, simply do this:

```
(string-split "this is a string")
=> '("this" "is" "a" "string") ; a list of strings
```

But if you really want to convert a string into a list of symbols, do this:

```
(define (convert string)
  (map string->symbol          ; convert each substring into a symbol
       (string-split string))) ; split the string by its spaces

(convert "this is a string")
=> '(this is a string) ; actually, a list of symbols (not strings!)
```

Comment: I get `string-split: undefined; cannot reference undefined identifier` error for `string-split`. I looked up documentation and it is a pre-defined function. I am not sure why I am getting this error

Comment: @mykhailo are you using Racket? if so, it's because of the language you're using, write `#lang racket` at the top of the file and make sure that the option "detect language from source" is enabled. If you're _not_ using Racket, then you should import the missing procedure from an external library or switch to a different interpreter that supports `string-split`.